# no encuentro el error para conectarme remotamente a un servidor mysql por el puerto 3306

Tags: mysql

trate con muchos posibilidades y repetí el proceso varias veces pero no encuentro la falla.

1- ya edite el archivo `etc/mysql/mysqld.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` blin-adress puse los 0.0.0.0 y habilite las opciones de basic-settings tambien agregue skip networkin.

[image: .]
[image: .]

el archivo my.cnf solo direcciona al archivo mysqld.cnf

2- cree el usuario 'rtmiac' con 'grats options'.

[image: .]

reinicie mysql: service mysql restart

al usar el comando:

```
mysql -u rtmiac -h 192.168.0.146(ip pc remoto) -p
```

sale este error:

```
cant connet to mysql server on 192.168.0.146 (111)
```

tampoco conecta con workbrench.
localmente funciona ok el usuario.

ufw ya habilite el puerto

[image: .]

no entiendo por que dice que solo escucha 127.0.0.1:3306
al usar el comando netstat -plutn | grep 3306

sale este error que apenas encontré ahora.

[image: .]

Comment: por favor su ayuda, llevo como 8 dias buscando la solución. soy nuevo en el tema.

Comment: De casualidad estás practicado ethical hacking?

Comment: ¿Responde [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111) a tu pregunta?

Comment: De casualidad estás practicado ethical hacking? directamente no, es un proyecto nuevo para la empresa, a mi me gusta la seguridad por eso necesito saber bien que pasa aca, para no cometer error en produccion. ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? – r4ziel hace 4 horas
no, yo ya hice y tengo todo igual.por eso mande las imagenes, para que sepan como esta y que puede estar faltando o que debere cambiar.

Answer (score 0):

las versiones que estaba usando son ubuntu 20.04 y mysql 8.0.20 y nunca me dio acceso remoto a mysql, durante 15 dias probe de todo, hoy probe con ubuntu 18.04 y mysql 5.7 y me demore 15 minutos con las mismas configuraciones. gracias.